# Where should I design skeletons and animations?

Tags: animation, blender, unreal, skeletal-animation

I have just finished a course on Unreal Engine 5, where I have been introduced to managing animations through skeletons and different meshes.

My question is, where should I design such animations? Are skeletons and animations designed with external software, such as Blender, and then imported to Unreal Engine, or are these things created later with Unreal once I have a general design of the character from Blender?

Maybe the question is really basic, but I'm not sure which of those options is better or if it doesn't matter at all. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you'd create your character model, add a skeleton, rig the model, and create animations all in external software like Blender or Maya.

However, Epic has been extending Unreal's built-in capabilities in these areas. In particular, you can now use control rig and sequencer to create and edit animation sequences in-engine. There's actually a new editor mode just for this in UE5: https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/animation-editor-mode-in-unreal-engine/

Unreal also has some 3D modeling capabilities, but I don't think you can rig your models with a skeleton in the editor just yet.